# Android Studio Port 5037 error

Tags: memory, android, android-studio, dart

Whenever I run virtual emulator to test my code on android studio system starts hanging very much and then it runs the virtual device with

> ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

And I am unable to test my code.

Also my system specs are i5 7th generation and 4GB RAM. What could be the reason for system getting hang or it is due to the above error?

Answer (score 5):

You need to first run `adb start-server` and then run `emulator -avd <avd_name>`